# Do you like languages that let you put the "then" before the "if"?

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I was reading through some C# code of mine today and found this line:

```
if (ProgenyList.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) return;
```

Notice that you can tell without scrolling that it's an "if" statement that works with ItemContainerGenerator.Status, but you can't easily tell that if the "if" clause evaluates to "true" the method will return at that point.

Realistically I should have moved the "return" statement to a line by itself, but it got me thinking about languages that allow the "then" part of the statement first. If C# permitted it, the line *could* look like this:

```
return if (ProgenyList.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated);
```

This might be a bit "argumentative", but I'm wondering what people think about this kind of construct. It might serve to make lines like the one above more readable, but it also might be disastrous. Imagine this code:

```
return 3 if (x > y);
```

Logically we can only return if x > y, because there's no "else", but part of me looks at that and thinks, "are we still returning if x <= y? If so, what are we returning?"

What do you think of the "then before the if" construct? Does it exist in your language of choice? Do you use it often? Would C# benefit from it?

Comment: What about `x = 3 if (a < b)`? How far do you want to take it? Just as an extension to `return`, or something more general? What about `{ ... /* multiple lines */ ... } if (a >= b)`

Comment: Interesting, but more often that not the 'if' triggers a code block, not a simple operation.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it only makes sense on return statements where it's a bit less ambiguous. Weigh in with a full answer if you like, @codeka! It's CW so it's not for rep.

Comment: Btw, the method will return if the "if" clause evaluates to *true*, not false :)

Comment: Oops! Better fix that now. Thanks Jon.

Comment: **A general solution**: If you'd write properly formatted code your `return` would be in a new line (and inside braces). then it would be more than obvious what's going on in that particular `if` statement. **There! Problem solved!**

Answer (score 14):

Let's reformat that a bit and see:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

...

if (ProgenyList.ItemContainerGenerator.Status != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
{
    return;
}
```

Now how hard is it to see the return statement? Admittedly in SO you still need to scroll over to see the whole of the condition, but in an IDE you wouldn't have to... partly due to not trying to put the condition and the result on the same line, and party due to the `using` directive.

The benefit of the existing C# syntax is that the textual order reflects the execution order - if you want to know what will happen, you read the code from top to bottom.

Personally I'm not a fan of "return if..." - I'd rather reformat code for readability than change the ordering.

Comment: Well, with anonymous methods and lamdba expressions, textual order doesn't necessarily reflect execution order.

Comment: @Senthil: True - but I think in that case the benefits outweigh the costs. In this situation I really don't think that's the case.

Comment: I don't like that it takes four lines of code to express such a simple concept.

Comment: @Jacob if you prefer, that construct has an equivalent inline style, removing the curly braces, and placing the return after the end paren.

Comment: @Jim of course, but then being able to put the return first is clearer imo.

Comment: @Jacob and I would agree that a language should let you choose.

Comment: @Jacob: You could remove the braces of course, to get it down to two lines - or possibly put the open brace on the same line as the "if" and the close brace on the same line as the "return".

Comment: I might be a bit biased on this because I've just discovered the feature in ruby (I'm a C# dev, but we're using rake for builds) and at the moment everything looks like a nail :P I like how it puts the important part (raise/return) in plain view, yet still only takes one line of code. Brilliant!

Comment: @Jacob: Does this crop up sufficiently often in your code that using one line instead of two or four is actually an issue? I find the logic of test-then-execute is more important than putting everything on one line. Ultimately you need to understand both the action and the condition anyway, don't you?

Comment: @Jon: I like that the most important part is first. Seeing a return or a throw changes the context of what follows quite significantly. 

As for one line vs four, it's not that significant, but shorter is almost always better imo. I find that often C# presents me with far more text than required to describe a concept.

Answer (score 10):

I don't like the ambiguity this invites. Consider the following code:

```
doSomething(x)
if (x > y);
doSomethingElse(y);
```

What is it doing? Yes, the compiler could figure it out, but it would look pretty confusing for a programmer.

Comment: That's a great example of the ambiguity this could introduce. Perhaps if it was limited to "return" statements? I dunno.

Comment: Where is the ambiguity? All you have done is inserted a new line.

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity. It's perfectly clear how this would be parsed.

Comment: @liammclennan, @Blindy: The ambiguity is here. if(x>y); doSomethingElse(y); The programmer may tend to read it as if(x>y) doSomethingElse(y);

Comment: not at first glance. Whether `doSomething` or `doSomethingElse` is conditionally executed is only a matter of where that first semicolon is placed. It is easier to comprehend this as `doSomething(x); if(x>y){ doSomethingElse(y); }` so a developer might naturally read it as so and mess something up. Better to be clear.

Comment: To clarify: I don't see it as ambiguity to the compiler, just to the human reader (if they don't pay close attention to the semicolons).

Comment: Yea, not to mention that some languages <cough> Python </cough> don't treat the ';' a  a line delimiter

Comment: Yes, all the languages I know that use this construct wouldn't allow that code anyway. Besides, the code is purposely ambiguous - this is not about how bad you can make it if you try. This is about responsible programmers writing readable code.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. 
It reads better. Ruby has this as part of its syntax - the term being '[statement modifiers](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html)'

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "Yay Ruby!" if 2 == 2
Yay Ruby!
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> puts "Yay Ruby!" if 2 == 3
=> nil
```

To close, I need to stress that you need to 'use this with discretion'. The ruby idiom is to use this for one-liners. It can be abused - however I guess this falls into the realm of responsible development - don't constrain the better developers by building in restrictions to protect the poor ones.

Answer (score 4):

It's look ugly for me. The existing syntax much better.

```
if (x > y) return 3;
```

Comment: It only looks ugly because you're not used to it. Same thing when learning a new language. At first the grammar is weird, disconcerting, and just plain wrong. However, you get used to it and start thinking in that language and it makes more sense... Japanese is a good example: "Tomorrow red car with sunroof want to buy" that's a transliterated sentence. The verb is always ( pretty much ) the last thing you say. Which means you establish the parts of the phrase at the beginning, the subject, the object and then you join them together at the end. It's just different that's all. Same as this code

Comment: Right. but things in any language are in one form, to prevent confusing. and if we let to write same statement both from the end the the beginning and from the beginning to the end, this will be very confusing, because you read something but you don't know immediately, if this is the beginning or the end.

Comment: it's equally correct, and not confusing, in English to say "I will buy the red car if I have enough money" vs "If I have enough money I will buy the red car". Giving the programmer the option allows them to put more emphasis on what is important.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's probably OK if the scope were limited to just `return` statements. As I said in my comment, imagine if *this* were allowed:

```
{
   doSomething();
   doSomethingElse();

   // 50 lines...

   lastThink();
} if (a < b);
```

But even just allowing it only on `return` statements is probably a slippery slope. People will ask, "`return x if (a);` is allowed, so why not something like `doSomething() if (a);`?" and then you're on your way down the slope :)

I know other languages do get away with it, but C#'s philosophy is more about making The One Right Way<sup>TM</sup> easy and having more than one way to do something is usually avoided (though with exceptions). Personally, I think it works pretty well, because I can look at someone else's code and know that it's pretty much in the same style that I'd write it in.

Comment: `doSomething() if (a);` is perfectly fine. Your example however... probably couldn't be implemented. It would only be limited to single statement expressions.

Comment: C# doesn't try for 'one right way'. I can think of at least 4 different ways to do conditionals in C#, 2 completely different LINQ syntaxes, 4 different ways to iterate, etc What is this slippery slope you speak of?

Comment: it looks like a `do/while` expression.

Comment: `do/while` is different because you always execute the statement in the block at least once.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem with

```
return 3 if (x > y);
```

It probably bothers you because you are not accustomed to the syntax. It is also nice to be able to say

```
return 3 unless y <= x
```

This is a nice syntax option, but I don't think that c# needs it.

Comment: Yes, Ruby allows the unless keyword. `return 'success!' unless errorCount > 0` as opposed to `return 'success' if errorCount < 1` It could be argued that the first statement is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think Larry Wall was very smart when he put this feature into Perl. The idea is that you want to put the most important part at the beginning where it's easy to see. If you have a short statement (i.e. not a compound statement), you can put it before the `if`/`while`/etc. If you have a long (i.e. compound) statement, it goes in braces after the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like languages that let me choose.

That said, if you refactor as well as reformat, it probably doesn't matter what style you use, because they will be equally readable:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

...
var isContainersGenerated = 
    ProgenyList.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated;

if (!isContainersGenerated) return;
//alternatively

return if (!isContainersGenerated);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a concern reading the code that you think a statement **will** execute only later to find out it **might** execute.

For example if you read "doSomething(x)", you're thinking "okay so this calls doSomething(x)" but then you read the "if" after it and have to realise that the previous call is conditional on the if statement.

When the "if" is first you know immediately that the following code **might** happen and can treat it as such.

We tend to read sequentially, so reading and going in your mind "the following might happen" is a lot easier than reading and then realising everything you just read needs to be reparsed and that you need to evaluate everything to see if it's within the scope of your new if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Both Perl and Ruby have this and it works fine. Personally I'm fine with as much functionality you want to throw at me. The more choices I have to write my code the better the overall quality, right? "The right tool for the job" and all that.

Realistically though, it's kind of a moot point since it's pretty late for such a fundamental addition in C#'s lifecycle. We're at the point where any minor syntax change would take a lot of work to implement due to the size of the compiler code and its syntax parsing algorithm. For a new addition to be even considered it would have to bring quite a bit of functionality, and this is just a (not so) different way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Humans read beginning to end. In analyzing code flow, [limits of the short term memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) make it more difficult to read postfix conditions due to additional backtracking required. For short expressions, this may not be a problem, but for longer expressions it will incur significant overhead for users that are not [seasoned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_(psychology)) in the language they are reading.

Comment: It just takes getting used to it. Humans are remarkably adaptable. Look at Tagalog... `Na kay Tatay ang susi` transliterated is `At with Father the keys` translated is `"Father has the keys."` I'm sure Tagalog speakers would feel at home with `return x if <condition>`

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with confusing , I never heard about this construction before , so I think correct way using then before if must always contents the result of else, like

```
return (x > y) ? 3 : null;
```

else way there is no point of using Imperative constructions like

```
return 3 if (x > y);
return 4 if (x = y);
return 5 if (x < y);
```

imho It's kinda weird, because I have no idea where to use it...

Answer (score 0):

It's like a lot of things really, it makes perfect sense when you use it in a limited context(a one liner), and makes absolutely no sense if you use it anywhere else.

The problem with that of course is that it'd be almost impossible to restrict the use to where it makes sense, and allowing its use where it doesn't make sense is just odd.

I know that there's a movement coming out of scripting languages to try and minimize the number of lines of code, but when you're talking about a compiled language, readability is really the key and as much as it might offend your sense of style, the 4 line model is clearer than the reversed if.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a useful construct and a programmer would use it to emphasize what is important in the code and to de-emphasize what is not important. It is about writing intention-revealing code.

I use something like this (in coffeescript):

> index = bla.find 'a'
>   return if index is -1

The most important thing in this code is to *get out (return) if nothing is found* - notice the words I just used to explain the intention **were in the same order as that in the code**.

So this construct helps me to code in a way which reflects my intention slightly better.

It shouldn't be too surprising to realize that the order in which correct English or traditional programming-language grammar has typically required, isn't always the most effective or simplest way to create meaning.

Sometimes you need to let everything hang out and truly reassess what is really the best way to do something.

Answer (score -1):

It's considered grammatically incorrect to put the answer before the question, why would it be any different in code?

Comment: Right, but this isn't putting the answer first, it's putting the ACTION first. "Buy eggs if we're out" isn't grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I'll leave a rebuttal here if that's ok with you. :)